# How to print out the last patterns range using awk?

Tags: awk

My file is like this:

> /begin pattern/
>  first match
>   /end pattern/
>
> other text
>
> /begin pattern/
>  second match
>   /end pattern/
>
> other text
>
> /begin pattern/
>  This is the one I
>   want to print out
>  /end
>   pattern/
>  other text

How can I print out the last match using awk? I just know about how to print out all these matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'END { print r } 
/end pattern/ { f = x }
/begin pattern/ { f = 1; r = x }
f++ > 1 { r = r ? r RS $0 : $0 }
' infile
```

Comment: 'Tis interesting how `x` is used.  In the `/end pattern/`, it is effectively `0`; in the `/begin pattern/`, it is effectively `""` (the empty string).  It is never set to anything.  IMO, it would be clearer to use `0` and `""`.

Comment: It'll function of course but it's pretty odd to see the END statement at the start of the script instead of at the end of it. Also, I stared at this for ages trying to figure out the difference between `r` and `x` before realizing you're using the unset variable `x` as a null string! Don't obfuscate your code that severely to save typing one more character - `f` is a number and `r` is a string so rather than `f=x` and `r=x` with an unset variable `x`, just use `f=0` and `r=""` as appropriate.

Comment: Now I understand what the code is doing - it'll fail (skip them) when the first lines after `begin pattern` are `0` or are empty. It'll also print any lines after a `begin pattern` at the end of the file when no `end pattern` exists rather than printing the last set of lines between `begin pattern` and `end pattern`, and it'll print a blank line if no matching block exists in the input.

Comment: @EdMorton: That's pretty subtle!  The `r = r ? r RS $0 : $0` conditional assignment evaluates `r` as 'false' if the line before contained `0` (or `00` or `0.0` or "`0 `", etc), or if it was empty (but not if the line contained only a blank).  Fixing that requires more engineering work.  The `f++ > 1` condition ensures the begin pattern line is ignored.  Using `f` or `f == 1` would include the begin pattern in the output.  To include the end pattern in the output, you'd have to add `$0` to `r` in the end pattern actions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right IF you have a version of awk that retains the value of `$0` in the `END` section. The value of `$0` in `END` is not specified by POSIX (only `NF` is) and so YMMV. The real solution for including the `end pattern` line for portability and so as to avoid duplicating code is to just move the test for `end pattern` to after the line where f is evaluated and `r` is populated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this "printing text in a range" stuff is one of those things that's WAY more complicated than it sounds. We haven't even touched on partial matches, full line matches, full word matches, string vs regexp matches, and cases where the start and end strings might appear on the same line or mid-line. It's so easy to come up with a "solution" that works for a posted sample input set and then blows up 6 months later running on real customer data!

Comment: @EdMorton: Agreed!   Fortunately, for many people, they won't run into the problems, but they're there.  The edge cases here are fascinating!

Comment: And don't get me started on nested blocks `start start start the target end end end` :-)!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on if you want the lines containing the delimiters printed or not:

```
$ awk '
    /begin pattern/ { rec=""; f=1 }
    f { rec=rec $0 ORS; if (/end pattern/) {last=rec; f=0} }
    END { printf "%s", last }
' file
/begin pattern/
This is the one I want to print out
/end pattern/
```

or:

```
$ awk '
    f { if (/end pattern/) {last=rec; f=0} rec=rec $0 ORS }
    /begin pattern/ { rec=""; f=1 }
    END { printf "%s", last }
' file
This is the one I want to print out
```

That ensures that what you print is a block starting with `begin pattern` and ending with `end pattern` so you don't just print a bunch of lines following a `start pattern` with no `end pattern` if such exists at the end of your input file. It also ensures you don't print a blank line if no matching block exists in the input.

Comment: If you used `awk '/begin pattern/,/end pattern/'` and there was a begin pattern near the end with no end pattern after it, that material would be printed.  The question doesn't address what's required when that happens — it would require a second example input.  You document that you regard the 'incomplete block' as something not to be printed — is it worth documenting what to do if the incomplete block should be printed?  I think it becomes `END { if (f) last = rec; printf "%s", last }`, doesn't it — at least for the 'no delimiters' code.

Comment: I never use range expressions as they save a couple of characters over using a flag for trivial problems and then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when the problem gets even slightly interesting so in my mind they're just never worth bothering with. If an incomplete block is to be printed then off the top of my head I think you don't have a `last` variable at all and just print `rec`.

Comment: Ah — yes, you're probably right about not using `last` and simply printing `rec`.

Answer (score 1):

Store the current match and use the END block to print it out:

```
awk '/end pattern/{flag=0} flag{m=$0} /begin pattern/{flag =1}  END{print m}' file
```

This works if there is only one line between /begin pattern/ and /end pattern/.