# Awk Pattern Ranges - How to Print the Last Range Match Only

Tags: bash, awk, text-processing

Given the block of text at the bottom;
Using

```
awk '/start===/,/end===/'
```

Will return all matches between the two ranges. I am looking to print only the last match in the range so expect the following only

```
  start===
     Fifth Line
     Six Line
   End===
```

Text to process below

```
 Random Line 0
start===
    First Line
    Second Line
end===
  Random Line 1
  Random Line 2
start===
    Third Line
    Fourth Line
end===
  Random Line 3
start===
    Fifth Line
    Six Line
End===
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448626/how-to-print-out-the-last-patterns-range-using-awk

Comment: Fantastic. Cheers